# Retun customer registration by month and first channel

Tags: mysql, sql, analytics, data-analysis

I have customers and their registration dates. I also have a customer channel. The customers can change their channel whenever.
I want to write a query that returns customer registrations by month and their first channel.

I tried this query. It does not result in an error but it's not the right answer. :

```
select distinct(customer_id) as cust_id, 
extract(month from created_date) as month,
min(created_date)
customer_channel as channel
from orders
group by cust_id, created_date, channel
```

Comment: Hi can you mention all column in your customer table?

Comment: can you share field types and sample records for each table?

Comment: @ChristianMahardhika the table has more than 50 columns. Are you looking for something specific? There is also a join which I've not included.

Comment: @lemon, customer_id is varchar, created_date is timestamp, customer_channel is varchar.

Comment: Please note that my query does not result in an error. It's just not the right answer.

Comment: @an_analyst hmm... ok can you show your expect result?